# .swf file opening on localhost/webserver IIS 7 but not from the internet

Tags: flash, iis-7

I am facing a strange behavior. My website has banner which loads .swf file. The file opens when I access my website internally but when I access from outside over the internet, IIS logs giving 200 0 121 Code for the request. And on the browser it give err_conn_timeout. I tried downloading a sample .swf file and tried accessing same behavior. All the other image files under that directory is opening like a charm but this .swf file is not opening. .Swf also added to mime types as well.

Please Help.

Comment: No one can see what you're doing wrong. Any way to put example page online? Also try to show the code part used to embed the SWF (maybe we'll see a path issue or such)

Comment: The exact same code is running on another web server internally and externally both. This particular swf file is opening like a charm on localhost or when I put my server's private IP in the host file. When I see the log file, the server is responding 200 but it is not reaching to client like our browsers. I tried different browsers too. I tried different swf files too. All those files are opening on local IP but not from internet. I have set .swf in MIME Type as well.

Comment: Is the swf saved online (eg: `http://www.example.com/myFlash.swf`)? You used `<embed src="http://www.example.com/myFlash.swf">`? Also If testing with Chrome, the swf needs minimum w=800 by h=600 or else you have to click to view it (is a grey box). Provide a direct path to the banner.swf and I'll test in my own embed code. Or save (right-click) and upload this [**sample.swf**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/helloworld.swf) then show path here for testing (URL path comment can be deleted later)

Comment: PS: what mime type you used for swf?

Comment: .swf application/x-shockwave-flash

Comment: The mime seems correct. With no link to check for any other errors (path issues etc) it's difficult to diagnose an invisible issue. Also try asking at : **https://serverfault.com/** (use your account there to click "Join this community" and just copy/paste your issue in a new Question).